# How to match user input from retrieved array?

Tags: reactjs

hello i am now able to retrieve data from spreadsheets using tabletops

but now i need to match the user input to the array and if it matches it'll be a success

this is inside the render

```
const { data } = this.state
        const tabletopModel = data['token']
        const newData = tabletopModel ? tabletopModel.all() : null
        console.log('newData', newData)
```

this is inside the return()

```
{
    newData
        ? <div>

            <p>{newData[1].ID}</p>
            <p>{newData[1].氏名}</p>


        </div>
        : null
}
```

i tried doing this or hopefully it should like this??

```
 {
    if (row1.アドレス == document.getElementById('userEmail').value && row1.Passkey == document.getElementById('userPassword').value) {
        return (
            <div key={row1.ID}>
                <p>{row1.ID}</p>
                <p>{row1.氏名}</p>
                <p>{row1.アドレス}</p>
                <p>{row1.Passkey}</p>
                <p>{row1.token}</p>
            </div>

        )
    }
    else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note*: You shouldn't use `document.getElementById()`, because it works with the actual DOM and React might not re-render when there are changes in input.

What you should do is have an input field in your React code and a proper `onChange` handler for that input field, like [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

Then, you can write a handler like this:

`onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    // do comparisons here or save input to state
    if(e.target.value === row1.data) {
        // do some stuff
    }
};`